# Which method call when we navigate from one fragment to another?

Tags: android

Which override method call when we navigate from one fragment to another?
for example i have two fragment one is "Home Fragment" and another is "chat Fragment". which method of chat fragment will be called when i navigate from home fragment to chat fragment?

Comment: Are you using fragment transaction or navigation?

Comment: just navigation through tab view

Answer (score 0):

The fragment being navigated to will go through its lifecycle up to the state of the Activity it's in.

So if the Activity is resumed, you'll get `onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume` (among others, such as `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated`, etc.) - exactly as it would if you added the Fragment at the beginning.